# Two Doubly linked lists are to be linked together by joining the Previous pointer of 1st list to the each consecutive node of 2nd list in cpp

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Examine the following code. Code is Error free but can someone tell why it is not working WHEN logic build is all okay.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class node {
   public:
    string data;
    node* next;
    node* prev;
    node() {
        data = " ";
        next = NULL;
        prev = NULL;
    }
    node(string data) {
        this->data = data;
        next = NULL;
        prev = NULL;
    }
};
class Nodes {
   public:
    node* upperList;
    node* lowerList;
    void pushFront(string upperdata, string lowerdata) {
        node* temp1 = upperList;
        node* temp2 = lowerList;
        node* t1 = new node(upperdata);
        node* t2 = new node(lowerdata);

        if (upperList == NULL && lowerList == NULL) {
            t1->next = NULL;
            t2->next = NULL;

            temp1 = t1;
            temp2 = t2;
            temp1->prev = temp2;
        }
        t1->next = upperList;
        upperList = t1;
        t2->next = lowerList;
        lowerList = t2;

        upperList->prev = lowerList;
    }
};
```

Comment: @Hassan Malik Show an example of contents of the lists and what result you are going to achieve.

Comment: You'll be glad to hear you don't need anyone's help to figure this out, just a tool you already have: your debugger! This is exactly what a debugger is for. It runs your program, one line at a time, and shows you what's happening. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all problems in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help. Have you tried using your debugger, already? If not, why not? What did your debugger show you?

Comment: The title talks about joining two doubly-linked-lists together (which btw should only require setting a fixed number of pointers, regardless of the lengths of the two lists; i.e. it should be an O(1) operation), but the code presented seems to be doing something different -- I'm not sure what.  Dunno if I misinterpreted the title, or if the code is badly flawed, or both :)

Comment: *"why it is not working"*: explain what is not working and provide the (driver) code to *reproduce* the problem with example input, and specifying what the expected result is. What you have presented does not create any list, but just defines classes.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik brother thanks for highlighting that! YES i have an idea of debugger and Debugger shows blank page when I compile my program Whereas my code written is all okay